# CI4 - Form Validation with multipart fromdata

Tags: php, validation, multipartform-data, codeigniter-4

I'm using CI4 validation library to validate my form on server side. Form tag is created using `form_open_multipart` helper function.
Here is the  sample code for HTML and controller

**ProductController.php**(Controller)

```
class ProductController extends BaseController
{
 ...

 public function create()
    {
        if (!$this->validateFrom()) {
            echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->validator->getErrors());die();
            $this->session->setFlashdata('validator', $this->validator);
            $this->session->setFlashdata('product_form', $this->request->getPost());
            return redirect('admin.product.new');
        }
        ...
    }
 private function validateFrom()
   {
    return $this->validate([
        'product_name' => [
            'label' => 'Product name',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => [
                'required' => '{field} is required.'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
  }

 ...

}
```

**ProductForm.php**(View File)

```
<?= form_open_multipart(route_to('prodyct.create'), ['id' => 'prodForm', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']); ?>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="product_name" class="col-4 col-form-label text-right">Product Name</label>
    <div class="col-8 p-0">
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control <?= $validator->hasError('product_name') ? 'is-invalid' : '' ?>"
               id="product_name"
               name="product_name"
               value="<?= $productForm->product_name ?? null ?>"
               placeholder=""/>
        <?php if ($validator->hasError('product_name')): ?>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                <?= $validator->getError('product_name'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="product_image" class="col-4 col-form-label text-right">Product Image</label>
    <div class="col-8 p-0">
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control <?= $validator->hasError('product_image') ? 'is-invalid' : '' ?>"
               id="product_image"
               name="product_image"
               value="<?= $productForm->product_image ?? null ?>"
               placeholder=""/>
        <?php if ($validator->hasError('product_image')): ?>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                <?= $validator->getError('product_image'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?= form_close(); ?>
```

On Form Submit, it always fails with validation even the value is provided.

```
Array
(
    [product_name] => Product Name is required.
)
```

When I check with method `withRequest` of `CodeIgniter\Validation\Validation` It seems that when it try to get data using `$this->data = $request->getRawInput();`, `getRawInput` is retruning null.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Ajax to send the data or just a post? Because getRawInput() is for parsing the ajax data body and not for post data. You will have to use $request->post() instead. Also you don't need seperate method just to validate the data. I think it is not a good practice to do so in the controller.

Comment: @DhavalChheda I'm simply posting a post data. And when I'm using a validate method of controller, It takes request object with DI and I only have to set Validation rules. But CI4 Incoming request is trying to read data from `php://input` without considering the content type, so it is an issue with framework and I'mm going to report this to contributor for this. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

i think instead of using `route_to('prodyct.create')` better using `base_url()`

like this..

```
<?= form_open_multipart(base_url('home/create'), ['id' => 'prodForm', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']); ?>
```

because when i try to `var_dump(route_to('some_route')` its return value is boolean `route_to(...) boolean false`

Comment: If you check the documentation of CI4 `route_to` is used to generate reverse routing. So It is used because if there is any change in Route URI then it is not necessary to go and find URI in all places in the project and update it. it will automatically adapt to this change.
 https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=route_to#route_to